# Magento 2: catalog rule takes too long to save

Tags: magento2, import, catalog-rules

I have created a command in magento 2 to insert multiple  catalogue rules in the `catalogerule` table, But in the afterSave method of the Model there is a method that loads whole collection of the products which filters the collection according to the condition of the rule, which takes more then 60 seconds for each catalog rule, and increases by each record. I have more then 1,80,000 products. Which is why it takes more time to load the cllection. Is there any suggestion using which i can speed up the process?

**Edit**

`afterSave` method that calls `getMatchingProductIds` method of the same class which loads the product collection.

```
public function afterSave()
    {
        if ($this->isObjectNew()) {
            $this->getMatchingProductIds();
            if (!empty($this->_productIds) && is_array($this->_productIds)) {
                $this->_ruleProductProcessor->reindexList($this->_productIds);
            }
        } else {
            $this->_ruleProductProcessor->getIndexer()->invalidate();
        }
        return parent::afterSave();
    }


 /**
     * Get array of product ids which are matched by rule
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getMatchingProductIds()
    {
        if ($this->_productIds === null) {
            $this->_productIds = [];
            $this->setCollectedAttributes([]);

            if ($this->getWebsiteIds()) {
                /** @var $productCollection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
                $productCollection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
                $productCollection->addWebsiteFilter($this->getWebsiteIds());
                if ($this->_productsFilter) {
                    $productCollection->addIdFilter($this->_productsFilter);
                }
                $this->getConditions()->collectValidatedAttributes($productCollection);

                $this->_resourceIterator->walk(
                    $productCollection->getSelect(),
                    [[$this, 'callbackValidateProduct']],
                    [
                        'attributes' => $this->getCollectedAttributes(),
                        'product' => $this->_productFactory->create()
                    ]
                );
            }
        }

        return $this->_productIds;
    }
```

The method that i have created to save the catalog rules.

```
protected function importCatalogRules(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $output->writeln('<info>Import started</info>');
        $output->writeln("<info>Fetching Data from IFS.</info>");
        $logger = $this->objectManager->create('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface');
        $appState = $this->objectManager->get("Magento\Framework\App\State");
        $appState->setAreaCode("admin");
        $rules = $this->getEntities();
        $i=0;
        foreach ($rules as $rule) {
            try{
                $model = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule');
                $model->load($rule['name'],'name');
                $validateResult = $model->validateData(new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($rule));
                $time = microtime(true);        
                if ($validateResult !== true) {
                    foreach ($validateResult as $errorMessage) {
                        $output->writeln("<info>".$errorMessage."</info>");
                        $logger->log($errorMessage);
                    }
                    continue;
                }
                $model->loadPost($rule);
                $model->save();
                $output->writeln("<info>".$rule['name']." Imported in ".round(microtime(true) - $time, 2)." seconds.</info>");
            }catch(\Exception $e){
                $output->writeln("<info>".$e->getMessage()."</info>");
                $logger->critical($e);
            }
            $ruleJob = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\Job');
            $ruleJob->applyAll();

            if ($ruleJob->hasSuccess()) {
                $this->objectManager->create('Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Flag')->loadSelf()->setState(0)->save();
            } elseif ($ruleJob->hasError()) {
                $logger->log($ruleJob->getError());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should post your code lines here.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh As suggested, i added the code.